# Why is my PHP file class recognized as text file?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm working on a Laravel project and when I was creating a new file I miss spelled the php extension ("php") but I didn't notice until I clicked enter so my PHP class files now appear as text files in PhpStorm and appears no hints whenever I write something in any php file.

[image: Problem]

Im using PhpStorm 2020.2.

Comment: It looks like ALL `.php` files are recognized as plain text and not just one.

Comment: Need more info: 1) Show what patterns **PHP file** entry has in `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types` 2) Does it really happens with ALL `.php` files .. or a single file only?

Comment: @LazyOne It happens with all php files. Altought blade.php get recognized right, they still have the same problem with hints. Answering your question, PHP patterns are : ".ctp",".hphp",".inc",".module",".php4",".php5" and ".phtml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate "PHP" entry in the top list (Recognized File Types)
3. Ensure that the middle list (File Name Patterns) has `*.php` entry there.

[image]

If it's not there then add it. Looks like you somehow re-assigned it to the "Text" file type.

[image]

[image]

---

> Altought blade.php get recognized right,

That's because `*.blade.php` is assigned to separate/dedicated "Blade" file type (so IDE can provide Blade-specific support there).

Answer (score 0):

And if you already did as @LazyOne suggested and your file still showing as text then right click the file and do this:

[image]